# Best way to gain performance when doing a join count using spark and scala

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, query-performance

i have a requirement to validate an ingest operation , bassically, i have two big files within HDFS, one is avro formatted (ingested files), another one is parquet formatted (consolidated file).

Avro file has this schema:

filename, date, count, afield1,afield2,afield3,afield4,afield5,afield6,...afieldN

Parquet file has this schema:

fileName,anotherField1,anotherField1,anotherField2,anotherFiel3,anotherField14,...,anotherFieldN

If i try to load both files in a DataFrame and then try to use a naive join-where, the job in my local machine takes more than 24 hours!, which is unaceptable.

```
ingestedDF.join(consolidatedDF).where($"filename" === $"fileName").count()
```

¿Which is the best way to achieve this? ¿dropping colums from the DataFrame before doing the join-where-count? ¿calculating the counts per dataframe and then join and sum?

PD

I was reading about map-side-joint technique but it looks that this technique would work for me if there was a small file able to fit in RAM, but i cant assure that, so, i would like to know which is the prefered way from the community to achieve this.

http://dmtolpeko.com/2015/02/20/map-side-join-in-spark/

Comment: can't you calculate the counts per dataframe and then join and sum?

Comment: I guess i can, @mtoto,  but, first, i would like to know which is the best way to achieve this. Actually i have running this sentence ingestedDF.join(consolidatedDF).where($"filename" === $"fileName").count() in order to know the number. When the job is done, i will try your suggestion. ¿ how should you write that code?

Comment: Not sure what the question is: Do you only want to know the count of common filenames in both datasets? or the difference?

Comment: the count of common filenames in both datasets, in a efficient way.

Comment: Are the filenames unique in both datasets?

Comment: filenames are unique within ingestedDF, but not within consolidatedDF. ingestedDF.count() : 2.758.070 records
consolidatedDF.count(): 26.190.406 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this problem by stripping down the data to only the field I'm interested in (`filename`), making a unique set of the filename with the source it comes from (the origin dataset).
At this point, both intermediate datasets have the same schema, so we can union them and just count.  This should be orders of magnitude faster than using a `join` on the complete data.

```
// prepare some random dataset
val data1 = (1 to 100000).filter(_ => scala.util.Random.nextDouble<0.8).map(i => (s"file$i", i, "rubbish"))
val data2 = (1 to 100000).filter(_ => scala.util.Random.nextDouble<0.7).map(i => (s"file$i", i, "crap"))

val df1 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data1).toDF("filename", "index", "data")
val df2 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data2).toDF("filename", "index", "data")

// select only the column we are interested in and tag it with the source.
// Lets make it distinct as we are only interested in the unique file count
val df1Filenames = df1.select("filename").withColumn("df", lit("df1")).distinct
val df2Filenames = df2.select("filename").withColumn("df", lit("df2")).distinct

// union both dataframes
val union = df1Filenames.union(df2Filenames).toDF("filename","source")

// let's count the occurrences of filename, by using a groupby operation
val occurrenceCount = union.groupBy("filename").count

// we're interested in the count of those files that appear in both datasets (with a count of 2)
occurrenceCount.filter($"count"===2).count
```

Comment: I have to prove it. I will post the numbers from my naive solution (not finished yet) confronted with your solution.

Comment: @aironman see it also in notebook form: https://gist.github.com/maasg/824e60cc522deada0986169dae733549

Comment: please, it is not a matter of If trusting you or not, it is a matter of testing with my data. Thank you with your assistance, I will post the data when the jobs finished.

Comment: hi @maasg. good morning, well, this query in my local machine (i7 2.5 GHZ 16GB RAM osx 10,12.2): ingestedDF.join(consolidatedDF).where($"filename" === $"fileName").count()  needed two days! to finish. With your help, 103 seconds... :) amazing and impressive. Thank you man! I have learned a lot with you.

Comment: Great!  Me debes la cerveza :-)

Comment: yeah! it should be a honor to drink with you as much beer as you can!